# Knockout binding issue with razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout and I'm trying to bind for example the 'first' variable so that it initialises and displayed properly during vm construction:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.first, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value:first" } })
```

and in my script section I declare the following:

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.first = ko.observable(data.first);
        self.second = ko.observable(data.second);

        self.third = ko.computed(function () {
            return  Number(this.first()) + Number(this.second());
        });
    };

    var data = { first: '1000', second: '1000' };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
```

Obviously I'm somewhere wrong, but dont know where.

Update: The rendered page:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-bind="value:first" data-val="true" data-val-number="my text" data-val-range="Please contact us" data-val-range-max="150000" data-val-range-min="5000" id="first" name="first" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: For clarity, can you show how the rendered html from the razor view?

Comment: Is that also a direct copy/paste of your code, because you've got a casing issue - `var ViewModel` vs `new viewModel` - this ought to show up as an error in your browser console

Comment: Curious question: What's the point of using a server side model+view to render a client side view so that the client can then take *another* model and render that into HTML?

Comment: @JamesThorpe updated the original question. thanks

Comment: So what's the actual issue - do you just not see the `1000` showing up in the input?  Have you opened your browser console (usually F12) - do you see any errors reported?

Comment: @No I don't see the 1000 showing up at all!. No errors are reported either. Will open the console and have a look

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks James, the issue was the first() and second() which are not functions. So now, I see the values, thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ah I see - they _are_ functions, but the value of `this` will be wrong in that context.  Since you're already using `self`, the quickest fix is to switch to `self.first()` and `self.second()`

Comment: @JamesThorpe ok will do. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you've got here is that your computed is trying to make use of `first` and `second`, but the value of `this` will be wrong in that context.  This means when knockout tries to evaluate the function, it will error, breaking the rest of the page.

The quickest fix, since you're already using `self` is to just use that within the computed:

```
self.third = ko.computed(function () {
    return  Number(self.first()) + Number(self.second());
});
```

An alternative fix is to make the value of `this` what you want, which can be achieved by using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
self.third = ko.computed(function () {
    return  Number(this.first()) + Number(this.second());
}.bind(this));
```

You'll see some of the knockout `computed` examples use this second form.